# SignalR: Server broadcast without persisting notifications

Tags: asp.net, notifications, signalr, real-time, aspnetboilerplate

I would like to notify online users that a new chat room has been created.  I don't need to notify offline users once they come online.

I looked at `AbpNotifications` but this seems to persist notifications and notify a user once they come online.  I only want to notify currently online users.

I looked at SignalR integration but could not find a way for the server to initiate a message.  For instance, I might want the `ApplicationService.ChatRoom.Create` method to initiate the message.

I did find documentation for how to get SignalR (outside of ABP) to initiate a message: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr#server

Answer (score 0):

Inject and use `IRealTimeNotifier`.

```cs
private async Task SendRealTimeNotificationsAsync(string message, UserIdentifier[] users)
{
    var data = new MessageNotificationData(message);
    var notification = new TenantNotification { Data = data };
    var userNotifications = users.Select(user => new UserNotification
    {
        TenantId = user.TenantId,
        UserId = user.UserId,
        Notification = notification
    });

    await RealTimeNotifier.SendNotificationsAsync(userNotifications.ToArray());
}
```

More info:
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Notification-System#real-time-notifications